# Load extension in python discordpy

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How i can solve the problem with importing another file where was used cog in discordpy??

```
import discord 
from random import randint, choice
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import utils

from . import config

class CommandErrors(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

#Error solving
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.CommandNotFound ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } something went wrong, please write command ``.help`` to see all commands of server.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.CommandInvokeError ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } something went wrong, please tell GrizzlyXGod_ to solve the problem.' )

@clear.error
async def clear_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please specify the number of messages to clear ``ex: .clear 100``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )

@mute.error
async def mute_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .mute @name``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you wrote something wrong please try again ``ex: .mute @name``' )

@unmute.error
async def unmute_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .unmute @name``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you wrote something wrong please try again ``ex: .unmute @name``' )

@kick.error
async def kick_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .kick @name``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you wrote something wrong please try again ``ex: .kick @name``' )

@ban.error
async def ban_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .ban @name``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you wrote something wrong please try again ``ex: .ban @name``' )

@unban.error
async def unban_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .unban @name``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you wrote something wrong please try again ``ex: .unban @name``' )

@addrole.error
async def add_role_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .addrole @name @role``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .addrole @name @role``' )

@removerole.error
async def remove_role_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .addrole @name @role``' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.MissingPermissions ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } you don''t'' have permission to use this command.' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .addrole @name @role``' )

@userinfo.error
async def userinfo_error( self, ctx, error ):
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } please type correct ``ex: .userinfo @name`` ' )
    if isinstance( error, commands.errors.BadArgument ):
        await ctx.send( f'{ ctx.author.name } something gone wrong make sure that you have wrote the name correctly ``ex: .userinfo @name`` or make sure that user is the part of this server.' )

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_completion( self, ctx ):
    print(ctx.command.name + " was invoked successfully.")

#Connect
def setup(client):
client.remove_command("help")
client.add_cog(CommandErrors(client))

extensions = ['CommandCommands']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for ext in extensions:
        client.load_extension(ext)
```

I tried to import another cog file if you need the code from that file i can edit this question and add that part. Thank you very much for help.
I'd like to get the answer as fast you can!
and one more thing i trying to create the bot, can anyone told me how to write code to change prefix for server.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main file where you start the bot up from, you should be loading the extensions. It should contain:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(...) # or client, depending on what you've called it

# the elements are just the names of your .py files
cogs = ["events", "members", "owner"]

# you can also add the on_ready event as usual here if you'd like

# making sure the bot only loads the extensions if this
# file was executed directly and not imported
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    for cog in cogs:
        bot.load_extension(cog) # loads in each file, Cog, that you defined in the list
```

Then the respective cogs should follow this layout (but can also follow others):

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class CogName(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot # now you'll use self.bot instead of just bot when referring to the bot in the code

    # instead of bot.command(), you'll use this:
    @commands.command()
    async def cmd(self, ctx): # self is the first param because it's in a class
        # some code

    @commands.command()
    async def othercmd(self, ctx, arg1, *, arg2): # e.g. args work as normal
        # other code

    # this is how you register events, instead of using @bot.event
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # some code

# this setup function needs to be in every cog in order for the bot to be able to load it
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(CogName(bot))
```

---

**References:**

- [Example bot with cogs](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be) - As well as looking at cogs, this example also provides an insight into how you can let servers configure their own prefixes. Consider a DB such as json, sqlite etc.
- [Cogs in rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#cog-changes) - Changes from async to rewrite.
- [Another cog example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) - More in-depth look into them and some examples showing how they work.